# What CCTV software is available for Debian?

Tags: debian, software-rec, camera

Is there any good open source ip camera software out there?

I have tried zoneminder but my computer isn't compatible, and shinobi seems to only be for CentOS, Unbuntu and others but not Debian and that is what I am running.

Comment: If it runs in Ubuntu there's a very good chance it'll run in Debian.

Comment: https://www.ubuntupit.com/linux-camera-software-ip-webcam-cctv-security-camera-software/

Comment: https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/awesome-diy-security-camera-clients-linux/